# Long lines don't render correctly

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpftoolkit

I have a project with a canvas that the user can zoom and pan using the mouse.  The origin is marked with a blue cross running through the canvas.  As the user zooms in the line width of the markers is reduced to keep the them about 1 pixel wide on screen.  However, after zooming in about 10x the origin lines abruptly disappear.  It seems like the rendering engine is deciding that the line is too small to be displayed before applying the scaling transform.

What is strange is that when I do the same operation to a rectangle instead of a line I get the expected behavior (see the ScaleBox rectangle object in the code below).  Any ideas on what is causing the problem and how to fix it would be welcome.

Here is the relevant XAML:

```
    <Canvas x:Name="MouseCapture" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="WhiteSmoke" >
    <Canvas x:Name="ZoomPan">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform >
            <MatrixTransform x:Name="_zoomPanTransform" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle x:Name="ScaleBox" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="-50" Canvas.Top="-50" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Line x:Name="YOrigin" X1="-5000" X2="5000" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="Blue" />
        <Line x:Name="XOrigin" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="-5000" Y2="5000" Stroke="Blue" />
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

And the code behind:

```
Private Sub ZoomControl_PreviewMouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs) Handles MouseCapture.PreviewMouseWheel
    Dim scale As Double
    If e.Delta > 0 Then
        scale = 0.95
    Else
        scale = 1 / 0.95
    End If
    Dim center As Point = e.GetPosition(MouseCapture)
    Dim zoom As New ScaleTransform(scale, scale, center.X, center.Y)
    _zoomPanTransform.Matrix *= zoom.Value
    UpdateLineWidth()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateLineWidth()
    ScaleBox.StrokeThickness = 1 / _zoomPanTransform.Matrix.M11
    XOrigin.StrokeThickness = 1 / _zoomPanTransform.Matrix.M11
    YOrigin.StrokeThickness = 1 / _zoomPanTransform.Matrix.M11
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot when everything is working.

[image]

Here is a screenshot as 10x Zoom.  The origin lines have disappeared abruptly, but the black box still shows up as expected. (Note that only one side of the black box is visible because the rest is outside the visible region because of the zoom.)

[image]

edit: I figured out the problem see below

Comment: Are you sure your origin line is on the screen? It seems that it is out of view. Pan a little left to find out.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn Yes the line is definitly on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the line was too long.  If I reduce the length of the origin lines dynamically so that they are roughly the same length as the canvas, everything displays as expected.  If the line gets to be 100x or so longer than the canvas they abruptly disappear.  This is probably due to some rounding errors or optimization scheme.

Comment: This will happen only if the line is also very thin. If you do not reduce the stroke thickness the line won't disappear. Again, having a render-transformed Line with an always adjusted stroke thickness is not a good idea. You should consider drawing a non-scaled crosshair exactly in your drawing area, i.e. one line at (mouse-x, 0..height), the other at (0..width, mouse-y).

Comment: @Clemens Thank, this is what I ended up doing.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand why you would put these crosshair lines in the transformed Canvas anyway.

Instead of drawing them into the transformed canvas and fix their effective line width on every change of the transformation, you should simply place them in another canvas, which is not transformed, e.g. in the parent Canvas here:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MouseCapture" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="WhiteSmoke" >
    <Canvas x:Name="ZoomPan">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform >
            <MatrixTransform x:Name="_zoomPanTransform" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle x:Name="ScaleBox" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="-50" Canvas.Top="-50" Stroke="Black"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Line x:Name="YOrigin" X1="-5000" X2="5000" Y1="0" Y2="0" Stroke="Blue" />
    <Line x:Name="XOrigin" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="-5000" Y2="5000" Stroke="Blue" />
</Canvas>
```

In general, when you want to transform geometric shapes while keeping their stroke thickness, you should go for the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615632%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element and set [Path.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx) to a [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) with an appropriate [Geometry.Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.transform.aspx), like in the following example. Note that the transform is defined as static resource (with key `GlobalTransform`), so that in can be reused by multiple geometries.

```
<Path Stroke="Blue">
    <Path.Data>
        <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,-100" EndPoint="0,100" Transform="{StaticResource GlobalTransform}"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Good idea on putting the the cross hair lines in their own canvas.  Lol, I didn't think of this.  It will requires some tricky math to keep everything aligned when zooming (around a point) and panning but should be doable.  Also, note that path and line both derive from shape by overriding the DefiningGeometry property, so a path and a line are equivalent internally.

Comment: But it makes a big difference if you render-transform a Line or transform the LineGeometry of a Path.